# Can I avoid the string copy while conditionally inserting into a hash via split?

Tags: perl, performance

I'm building `%grouped` from `%uniq_c`, where `%grouped` contains the key/value pairs generated by splitting `%uniq_c`'s key IF `%uniq_c`'s value is high enough. It's fairly efficient, but I'd like to do better.

```
%uniq_c = (
    'foo:baz'   => 3,
    'foo:quux'  => 12,
    'bar:corge' => 15,
    'bar:fred'  => 8,
);

foreach my $gv (keys %uniq_c) {
        if( $uniq_c{$gv} >= 10 ) {
                my ($g, $v) = split /:/, $gv, 2;
                push( @{$grouped{$g}}, $v );
        }
}
```

I *think* there are three string copies happening per loop iteration; 1 for $g and 2 for $v. Is there a way to eliminate one of the $v copies, or better yet, a $v and a $g copy (some sort of string slicing perhaps)?

For reference, Data::Dump::dump(%grouped) produces the following:

```
(
  "bar", ["corge"],
  "foo", ["quux"],
)
```

Comment: What makes you believe there are string copies happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copying of the values returned by `split` is very efficient; the string buffer is stolen instead of copied. But there is another copy done when you push `$v`. All three of these copies can be avoided through aliasing.

```
use Data::Alias qw( alias );

foreach my $gv (keys %uniq_c) {
        if( $uniq_c{$gv} >= 10 ) {
                alias my ($g, $v) = split /:/, $gv, 2;
                alias push @{$grouped{$g}}, $v;
        }
}
```

Comment: "the string buffer is stolen": is that to say the l-value is written to directly by split, thus avoiding copying out of a temporary variable?

Comment: No, it means the assignment moves the pointer to the string buffer instead of copying the string buffer itself. As such, it works for every sub and function that returns temps, not just `split`.